# Requests Python, how to prettify this code and do something?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

so the problem is that I can't understand how to prettify this code, help me please
The code goes through the link tree in this site and I need to save all the files that are presented there. But I was stuck on the transition. I have no idea how to go through without loops inside loops

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = 'https://daten.gdz.bkg.bund.de/produkte/'
info = []


def get_hrefs():
    global link5
    r = requests.get(links)

    # print(r)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for linkse in soup.find_all('a'):
        link = linkse.get('href')
        # return links+link
        # print(links + link) take all links of href
        print('______________________')
        if '?C=' in link:
            pass
        else:
            r2 = requests.get(links + link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, 'html.parser')
            for linkse in soup.find_all('a'):
                link2 = linkse.get('href')
                # return links+link
                # print(links + link + link2)
                if '?C=' in link2:
                    pass
                else:
                    r3 = requests.get(links + link + link2)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r3.content, 'html.parser')
                    for linkse in soup.find_all('a'):
                        link3 = linkse.get('href')
                        # return links+link
                        # print(links + link + link2+link3)
                        if '?C=' in link3:
                            pass
                        else:

                            r4 = requests.get(links + link + link2 + link3)
                            soup = BeautifulSoup(r4.content, 'html.parser')
                            for linkse in soup.find_all('a'):
                                link4 = linkse.get('href')
                                # return links+link
                                print(links + link + link2 + link3 + link4)
                                if '?C=' in link4:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    try:
                                        r5 = requests.get(links + link + link2 + link3 + link4)
                                        soup = BeautifulSoup(r4.content, 'html.parser')
                                        for linkse in soup.find_all('a'):
                                            link5 = linkse.get('href')
                                            # return links+link
                                            print(links + link + link2 + link3 + link4 + link5)
                                            # info = links + link + link2 + link3 + link4 + link5

                                    except:
                                        info.append(links + link + link2 + link3 + link4 + link5)

        print('--------------------INFO')
        print(info)
        print("________________END")
def main():
    link = get_hrefs()
    # link2 = get_another_link(link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please elaborate the problem. The problem definition is unclear. Add some sample record from the data, and a more clear objective. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to traverse through link hierarchy and find out the final url for some file(zip) at the end.
Even if that's not the case what you should do is `Move repeating code into a function` and use of `recursion` to avoid any looping.

Following sample code prints out the final zip file link

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = 'https://daten.gdz.bkg.bund.de/produkte/'
info = []

def get_hrefs(rootlink):
    r = requests.get(rootlink)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for linkse in soup.find_all('a'):
        link = linkse.get('href')
        if '?C=' in link:
            pass
        elif link.endswith('.zip'):
            print("Final link ", rootlink + link)
            return
        else:
          get_hrefs(rootlink + link)
          
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_hrefs(links)
```